# Python right answer shows as wrong

Tags: python, file

I was looking at some code for a question game where the answers are read from a file, but when I run it, it tells me the answer is wrong even if it is right, have I typed it up wrong or is there something missing in the text file?

```
for line in lines:
question, rightAnswer = line.strip().split("\t")
answer = input(question + " ")
if answer.lower() == rightAnswer:
    print("Right!")
    numRight = numRight + 1
else:
    print("No, the correct answer is %s" % rightAnswer)
```

My text file is as follows:

```
How many strings does a guitar have?    Six
How many strings does a violin have?    Four
Are mandolin strings in pairs?  Yes
```

Comment: You are converting the anwer given to lower case, but the correct answers are not given in lower case. So if the user enters `Six` and the correct answer is `Six`, the program compares `"six" == "Six"` which is false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change `if answer.lower() == rightAnswer` to `if answer.lower() == rightAnswer.lower()`